# Firebase deployed flutter web page throws exception (since today) - why?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have a flutter web app with the following dependencies, updated today to most recent ones. There was no code change! Just version updates:

```
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.12
  firebase_core: ^2.6.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.4.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.2.7
```

Running the web app locally works fine (Chrome), but when I upload/deploy it to firebase, I get the following Exception:

```
VM155:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier 'Instance of 'TrustedScriptURL''
    at window.ff_trigger_firebase_core (<anonymous>:2:18)
    at mJ.v7 (main.dart.js:49235:19)
    at main.dart.js:52258:9
    at aJx.a (main.dart.js:6218:62)
    at aJx.$2 (main.dart.js:45146:14)
    at Object.M (main.dart.js:6204:10)
    at ag6.aqG (main.dart.js:52262:10)
    at ag6.BK (main.dart.js:52239:21)
    at ag8.$1 (main.dart.js:52332:15)
    at e9.q (main.dart.js:44287:19)
```

which is this statement

[image]

and the same exceptions for all other firebase packages:

[image]

The problem is, when I now revert back to the old firebase version, the problem stays! I don´t know what happened. Edge browser shows the same exception.

Thanks!